# Best way to structure an Excel VSTO project for multiple versions of Excel

Tags: vsto, excel-addins

I am converting a C# VSTO add-in to support multiple versions of Excel (2007, 2010, 2013). My current plan is to have 4 projects in the solution, the core functionality and the AddIn projects. My question is: is it possible to write the AddIn in such a way that it will work with all versions of Excel? If not, is there a common Excel object model that would work?

If there isn't a proscribed way to do it, I would extract out the functionality from the Excel object model into a set of classes/interfaces that could then pass through an adapter to get o the real objects, then have version specific projects that contain the adapters. However, this is a lot of work I'd like to avoid.

Thanks,
Erick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at these two options for office version independent addins:

1. [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/) is a free wrapper that does something similar to what you described in your second paragraph
2. [Addin express](http://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/wizards.php) is a similar (but commercial) framework

For the second option the development looks something like this:

- you select the lowest version of Office you wish to support
- you write the code against the object model of that version

Even with that you will still find some differences in how different versions of Excel work. For example [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/dn251093%28v=office.15%29.aspx) is one change that needs to be considered.

Comment: Thansk! Given your experience, do you prefer Addin Express?

Comment: I think that both options are quite similar if you only consider version neutrality. However Addin express has some additional features  that were the deciding factor for us. I think it would be best for you to check what both solutions offer to you and see which one fits your needs better.